# Making the URL SEO friendly from file in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess

I am trying to make my URLs SEO friendly. The current URLs example is http://example.com/details.php?recordID=35791

I would like it to display the 'Name Of Event' in the URL rather than `'details.php?recordID=35791'` from a MYSQL database

I have renamed the title by using `'?php echo $row_rsd1['Name Of Event'];'` in the php page already so the `tab` is showing correct.

I have too many records to manually rename.

Answer (score 0):

You can make like it.

```
www.example.com/event-detail-147854-group-meeting.php
```

here 147854 is record ID
and group meeting is title of event.

you can convert title into lower case and spaces replacing by dashes.

Then map in .htaccess file.

```
RewriteRule ^event-detail-([0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9_\-+]+).php event-detail.php?id=$1&title=$2
```